ContainerApp not pulling images from new Azure Container Registry
I have a Container App in Azure Cloud and I have created a new Azure Container Registry(ACR). With my pipeline I am generating image in my acr and then updating the container app to use the new ACR and pull new latest image from it. The images are successfully being created in the ACR however the container app is still not using the new ACR.
In my pipeline, first I am building new Image in the ACR:
parameters:
  - name: build_specific
    displayName: "(Optional) Build the specific Docker Image. Enter path to Dockerfile from Docker folder."
    type: object
    default:
  - name: dso_key
    displayName: "DSO key used for the ACR name."
    type: string
  - name: acr_subdir
    displayName: "Name of the ACR subfolder."
    type: string
  - name: pip_extra_index_url
    type: string
    default: "https://$(GLOBAL_FEED_NAME_PREFIX)$(FEED_NAME_SUFFIX):$(FEED-PAT)@pkgs.dev.azure.com/ADD"

jobs:
  - job: BuildCode
    displayName: "Create and run ACR tasks"
    pool:
      name: "Basic_Pool_Ubuntu"

    steps:
      - checkout: self
        submodules: true
      - checkout: templates
      - task: AzureKeyVault@2
        inputs:
          connectedServiceName: $(VAR_SERVICE_CONNECTION)
          keyVaultName: $(GLOBAL_KV_NAME)
          secretsFilter: "DEVOPS-PAT, FEED-PAT"
          runAsPreJob: false
      - task: PipAuthenticate@1
        inputs:
          artifactFeeds: '$(GLOBAL_FEED_NAME_PREFIX)$(FEED_NAME_SUFFIX)'
          onlyAddExtraIndex: true
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: "Create ACR Tasks"
        name: "createACRTask"
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: "$(VAR_SERVICE_CONNECTION)"
          scriptType: "bash"
          scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
          inlineScript: |
            ACR_NAME=$(GLOBAL_STAGE_LOWER)$(GLOBAL_DEPLOYMENT_LOWER)acr
            BRANCH_NAME=$(echo "$(Build.SourceBranch)" | sed 's/refs\a/heads\///g')
            CONTEXT="$(Build.Repository.Uri)#${BRANCH_NAME}"
            TASK_NAME=${VAR_STAGE_LOWER}_${{ parameters.dso_key }}_${{ parameters.acr_subdir }}
            IMAGE_NAME=${VAR_STAGE_LOWER}/${{ parameters.dso_key }}/${{ parameters.acr_subdir }}

            echo "Building file: ./$(Build.Repository.Name)/${{ parameters.build_specific }}"

            # Build command into azcommand for debugging purposes
            azcommand="az acr build \
              --registry ${ACR_NAME} \
              --image ${IMAGE_NAME}:cb$(Build.BuildId) \
              --image ${IMAGE_NAME}:latest \
              --file ./$(Build.Repository.Name)/${{ parameters.build_specific }} \
              --build-arg PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL=${{ parameters.pip_extra_index_url }} \
              ./$(Build.Repository.Name)/
            "
            # echo ${azcommand} # Uncomment to see exact command

            # Execute command without any parameter
            ${azcommand}



this works fine and in the next stage I am run az containerapp update with the following code:
parameters:
  - name: dso_key
    displayName: "DSO key used for the ACR name."
    type: string
  - name: acr_subdir
    displayName: "Name of the ACR subfolder."
    type: string

jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: "Deploy Container App"
    environment: "$(Build.Repository.Name)-$(Build.SourceBranchName)"

    pool:
      name: "Basic_Pool_Ubuntu"

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - checkout: self
            - checkout: templates
            - task: Bash@3
              inputs:
                targetType: "filePath"
                filePath: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/templates/helper_scripts/deployment_branch_gate.sh"
                arguments: $ENV_SOURCE_BRANCH $ENV_DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH
              env:
                ENV_SOURCE_BRANCH: $(Build.SourceBranchName)
                ENV_DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH: $(VAR_DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH)
              name: "Branch_Gate"
              condition: not(and(eq(variables['overwritebranchgate'], 'true'), eq(variables['VAR_DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH'], 'develop')))
            - task: AzureCLI@2
              displayName: "Deploy Container App"
              name: "DeployContainerApp"
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: "$(VAR_SERVICE_CONNECTION)"
                scriptType: "bash"
                scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
                inlineScript: |

                  CONTAINERAPP_NAME="$(VAR_CONTAINERAPP_NAME)"
                  RESOURCE_GROUP="$(VAR_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME)"

                  ACR_NAME="$(GLOBAL_STAGE_LOWER)$(GLOBAL_DEPLOYMENT_LOWER)acr.azurecr.io"
                  IMAGE_NAME="${VAR_STAGE_LOWER}/${{ parameters.dso_key }}/${{ parameters.acr_subdir }}"
                  TAG="cb$(Build.BuildId)"

                  CPU="$(VAR_CONTAINERAPP_CPU)"
                  RAM="$(VAR_CONTAINERAPP_RAM)"
                  MIN_SCALE="$(VAR_CONTAINERAPP_MINSCALE)"
                  MAX_SCALE="$(VAR_CONTAINERAPP_MAXSCALE)"
                  SCALE_HTTP_CONCURRENCY="$(VAR_CONTAINERAPP_SCALE_HTTP)"
                  ENV_VARS="$(VAR_ENVS)"

                  revision=$(bash pipeline-templates/helper_scripts/containerapp/update_container_app.sh \
                      "$CONTAINERAPP_NAME" \
                      "$RESOURCE_GROUP" \
                      "$ACR_NAME" \
                      "$IMAGE_NAME" \
                      "$TAG" \
                      "$CPU" \
                      "$RAM" \
                      "$MIN_SCALE" \
                      "$MAX_SCALE" \
                      "$SCALE_HTTP_CONCURRENCY" \
                      "$ENV_VARS")

                  echo "Deployed Revision '$revision'"
                  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=revision]$revision"

this is the update_container_app.sh:
CONTAINERAPP_NAME=$1
RG=$2

ACR=$3
REPO=$4
TAG=$5
CPU=$6 # 0.25-4
RAM=$7 # 0.1-8
MIN_SCALE=$8
MAX_SCALE=$9
SCALE_HTTP_CONCURRENCY=${10}
ENV_VARS=${11}

IMAGE="${ACR}/${REPO}:${TAG}"

container_revision=$(az containerapp update -n ${CONTAINERAPP_NAME} -g ${RG} \
    --image ${IMAGE} \
    --cpu ${CPU} \
    --memory "${RAM}Gi" \
    --min-replicas ${MIN_SCALE} \
    --max-replicas ${MAX_SCALE} \
    --scale-rule-name "http-scale-rule" \
    --scale-rule-type "http" \
    --scale-rule-http-concurrency ${SCALE_HTTP_CONCURRENCY} \
    --only-show-errors \
    --set-env-vars ${ENV_VARS} | jq -r ".properties.latestRevisionName")

echo $container_revision


Do you get any error/warning messages when running the update_container_app.sh script using the AzureCLI@2 task in the pipeline? Provide the detailed debugging logs of the task. In addition, if you manually run the same 'az containerapp update' with the same input parameter values from your local machine, does it work?

when I run the update_container_app.sh script using the AzureCLI@2 task in the pipeline, I am just getting the name of the revision for the ContainerApp

How about manually run the same 'az containerapp update' command with the same input parameter values (replace the variables with the actual values passed in the pipeline) from your local machine? Does it work? And did the pipeline ever work before? @SumitBhardwaj

Try to enable debugging logs when triggering the pipeline run. And do not pass the output of the 'az containerapp update' command to a variable. Just let it directly output and print to the pipeline logs window. @SumitBhardwaj

I checked the output for az containerapp update and even though I am passing the values of new ACR and Image, it is still taking the old image and ACR. Maybe it is just not recognizing the new image?

If you update from web site of Azure Portal, does it pick the latest image? If also not work, I am afraid that you did not correctly build and push the new docker image. In pipeline, you can try to use the Docker@2 task to run the 'docker build' and 'docker push' commands to build and push the new image. @SumitBhardwaj

It worked when I manually updated the ACR in the ContainerApp in Azure Portal

So, It does not work if you manually run the Azure CLI command 'az containerapp update' while it works when you manually update the container app from the web site of Azure Portal. Looks like, the problem is on the Azure CLI command itself.  @SumitBhardwaj

I attempt with the the 'az containerapp update' command in my pipeline, and it can work as expected to update the container app with the specified new image. And from the output json of this command, I can see the content liek as ""containers": [         {           "image": "brghtranacr.azurecr.io/myubuntu2204:576",           "name": "brghtranca",           . . .       ]," which shows the right image:tag is used by the container app. In addition, do the build job and deploy job run in the same pipeline, or in two different pipeline? @SumitBhardwaj

Based on my attempt, when running the 'az containerapp update' command and use the parameter '--image' (or -i) to pass an new image (registry/imageName:tag), if the specified image tag does not existing in the registry, the command will not throw any error/warning message for this. It still runs successfully and will not make update to container app. And from the output JSON of this command, we can see it still use the old image tag on the container app.

Based on the YAML you provided, you seem run the BuildCode job and Deploy job in two different YAML pipelines.
What you need to know that:

Every time when you trigger a new run of a YAML pipeline (or classic build pipeline), it will generate a unique BuildId for this new pipeline run.

The predefined variable $(Build.BuildId) can only return the BuildId of current pipeline.

When you run the BuildCode job in a pipeline run, the run has a unique BuildId. If you run the Deploy job in another pipeline run, this run also has a unique BuildId that is different than other runs.


You should put the BuildCode job and Deploy job in the same pipeline so that they can be executed in a same pipeline run every time. If so, the $(Build.BuildId) will return the same value in the two jobs every time.


Have you check with the suggestions mentioned in my answer above? Does it work for you? @SumitBhardwaj

Hey, sorry for the late reply. My BuildCode job and Deploy job is in the same pipeline, just in different stages so the BuildId will be same for both the Jobs. And I also checked in the portal, the tag do exist in the ACR before the az containerapp update is run.

@SumitBhardwaj, On the Deploy job, did you set it to dependsOn the BuildCode job so that the  Deploy job will run after the BuildCode job completed successfully? If you do not set the dependsOn relationship, the Deploy job might run before the BuildCode job that the image with the new tag has not been built and pushed to ACR.

Yes I had already set dependsOn and the az containerapp update doesnt run if the image is not created. I had to submit the project so I manually updated the ACR in the containerapp and now it is accepting the new image as desired. I really appreciate your input in my probem, thank you very much for everything! :)
